# External Persistant Bootable SSD Mac OSX

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, external-hdd

I've been trying to create a bootable external SSD. I have a 2013 MacBook Air, and a 128 GB external SSD. After a lot of trial and error I finally managed to install Ubuntu 14.04 with a ext4 partition, but it still won't boot properly. I created a bootable flash drive and used that to boot Ubuntu and run the installer/format the SSD. That worked successfully, but I'm still not able to boot from the SSD alone. I can boot from the flash drive, and the whole filesystem appears to be setup properly on the external SSD. I tried to fix it using a couple grub commands I found (here's the output http://paste.ubuntu.com/15378871/), and I managed to get the boot loader to recognize the drive (which it wasn't at first). But when I try to boot from it I get an error message and it fallback to OSX. The error message  disappears too fast for me to discern what it says. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. The solution was relatively trivial I had to install rEFInd.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)